# Executing function in ng-repeat give error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-show

I have to run a function during a ng-repeat like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in listaService track by $index">
   <td>{{x.label}}</td>
   <td><span ng-show="showNoRole(x.label)" id="bannerRole">Nessun Ruolo</span> </td>
</tr>
```

and in the angular controller I have this function for control the ng-show:

```
$scope.showNoRole = function(label) {
   RicercaRuoloService.load(label).then(function(data) {

      if (data != "\"null\"") {
         return false;
      } else {
         return true;

      }
   }, function(error) {
      $scope.ErroreConnessione = true;
   })
}
```

the function `RicercaRuoloService`returns an array or `"\"null\""`if the array is empty.
The problem is when I go to the page where is the ng-repeat the console start to print as loop this error:

```
angular.min.js:107 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at angular.min.js:6
    at r.$digest (angular.min.js:131)
    at r.$apply (angular.min.js:134)
    at g (angular.min.js:87)
    at T (angular.min.js:92)
    at XMLHttpRequest.w.onload (angular.min.js:93)
```

and the cpu usage go frof 20% to 100% until I close the page.
How can I fix this problem?
Best reguards

EDIT:
this is the array from listaService:

```
[{"_id":"test","label":"test","descrizione":"descrizione test","url":"http://www.virgilio.it","tipoProfilo":"NGPFNL","periodoValidazione":370,"direct":false,"preValid":false,"deleted":false},{"_id":"test2","label":"test2","descrizione":"descr test2","url":"http://www.google.com","tipoProfilo":"NGPFNL","periodoValidazione":123,"direct":false,"preValid":false,"deleted":false}]
```

EDIT2:
RicercaRuoloService is just an Angular service that call a rest service and take data form db. The rest service works great 'couse I used it for other page too but never as a function in a ng-repeat.

Comment: dont use minified version of `JS` for development. use only while in production

Comment: `Error: $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop
10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []`

Comment: I know but I have to use it.

Comment: can I check you array `listaService`

Comment: I edit the question with array from in 'listaService'

Comment: have you looked at the error in question in the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D)? From said error page **One common mistake is binding to a function which generates a new array every time it is called.**

Comment: So I have to write an other query that returns just a boolean..I will try It

Comment: can you share `RicercaRuoloService.load` service, thats where the real problem lies.

Comment: the service is just a call to a rest service that I used a lot of times as I wrote in the EDIT2 of the question. It return an array of object or null

Comment: @Craicerjack I try to use a query that just return a boolean but it doesn't works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one time binding. Right now your function is executed in every digest cycle of angularJS.

```
ng-show="::showNoRole(x.label)"
```

Also try

```
$scope.showNoRole = function(label) {
var result;
RicercaRuoloService.load(label).then(function(data) {

    if (data != "\"null\"") {
        result = false;
    } else {
        result = true;
    }
}, function(error) {
    result = false;
    $scope.ErroreConnessione = true;
})
return result;
}
```

Comment: If you remove the ng-show part does it still gives you the same error? Because if yes, then the problem is not with the showNoRole function. How do you initialize listaService?

Comment: the list works great because I used it without the ng-show a lot of times